# neo4j migration from different machines

Tags: neo4j

I have neo4j 1.8.M05 on a windows machine. I have installed the same version on a linux machine (ubuntu) and want to migrate data to linux. should I xcopy the /data folder? just /data/graph.db? or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just /data/graph.db works fine as [michael](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/6Cu7MYi_Sk4) mentions